# URL for core_course_create_courses

Tags: moodle-api

What does a URL have to look like so that I can create courses using the Moodle web services?

Example:

Full name: EDV King

Short name: EDV_King

Category: none

The web services in Moodle are activated.

My url:

http://localhost/moodle/webservice/rest/server.php?wstoken=MyToken&wsfunction=core_course_create_courses&moodlewsrestformat=json&courses[0][fullname]='EDV_King'&courses[0][shortname] ='EDV_King'&courses[0][categeoryid] ='1'

Unfortunately does not work.

Where is the mistake?

Thank you all for your help!

Answer (score 0):

here is the correct url:

http://localhost/moodle/webservice/rest/server.php?wstoken=MyToken&wsfunction=core_course_create_courses&moodlewsrestformat=json&courses[0][fullname]='EDV King'&courses[0][shortname] ='EDV_King'&courses[0][categoryid] =1

Nice Regards :-)